# Orchard Custom Forms

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am trying to create a custom form with a single input field with a submit button. The form should be displayed inline (submit button next to the input field). I tried floating and display inline, however I can't get it working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: .search-form input[type="text"] {
 float: left
}
    
.search-form button[type="submit"] {
 float: left 
}

Comment: You should tag this CSS, not Orchard. There is nothing Orchard-specific about this.